# Sikuli in Loop Mode

Tags: python, sikuli

I am new for Sikuli and Python.
My little program on Sikuli IDE is to open an app every 20mn and click on a Button
For now, I try to do that for 1 time execution but I need to know how to set the code in Loop and execute every 20mn.
The Code :

```
    find("img.png")
    doubleClick("img.png")
    find("img.png")
    click("img.png")
    find("img.png")
    click("img.png")
    wait(5)
    click("img.png")
    click("img.png")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap it in a loop like this:

```
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1200) #1200 sec = 20 min
    #your code
```